# Linux: VI - When someone say "Command mode key sequence", what are they talking about?

Tags: linux, centos, vi

On one of my Linux VI assignment, I'm asked

> Delete the first 2 lines in this file using one **dd command**. What
>   command mode key sequence did you enter?

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what it's asking me.
What does it mean when it says "Command mode **key sequence**" ?

Is it asking me to use **dd** in the command mode (that's my answer), or is it asking me to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its asking you to use a `dd` in command mode.

In Vi editor, when you press `[Esc]` and type `:` you are in the command mode, now if you type `dd` `[Enter]` whichever line your cursor is on gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

`vi` has two basic modes: *command-mode* and *insert-mode*.  You start in command-mode, and may temporarily be in insert-mode for `i` (insert), `o` (open) and similar commands.  Type <kbd>escape</kbd> to return to command-mode.

There is another way to enter commands, referred to as *ex* (originally a different program from `vi`, but integrated for a long time).  For that, you temporarily exit *visual* mode by typing <kbd>:</kbd> (colon).

Some command-mode commands are "stuttered" (repeated characters), such as `dd`.  That happens to correspond to the ex-command **`d`** (delete line).

Further reading:

- [Basic vi Commands](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html)
- [Vi Cheat Sheet](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html)